# How to move only specfic folders from one directory to another?

Tags: windows, powershell

Example : I have a directory named `downloads` where I have 5 folders, say:

```
1.abc.123.456 
2.xyz.567.ghj
3.pqr.456.33.ff 
4.abc.45.pqr
5.abc.hjks.2334
```

Now I want to move all the folders starting with abc along with their subdirectories and files to another folder in maybe same directory or another.

```
#Change $Source and $Dest accordingly
$Source = "D:\Downloads"
$Dest = "D:\Downloads\abc"
$Pref = 'abc'
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Force -File | ForEach-Object {
    if (($_.BaseName.Length -gt 15 ) -and ($_.BaseName.Substring(0, 15) -eq $Pref)) {
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$($Dest)\$($_.BaseName)$($_.Extension)"        
    }
}
```

Comment: So, does your not work? What results are you getting?

Comment: Do the directory names begin with a digit, or was that just to list them?  Should the first three (3) letters of the directory name be 'abc'?

Comment: "I want to move all the folders starting with abc" - none of the folder names listed start with `abc`, they all start with a decimal digit